# The context cannot be used while the model is being created [Using different connection string on runtime]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I've multiple databases for a single application. I'm using EF. I changed the connection string on request. Connection string is stored in cache. When multiple user for multiple database put request it goes to slow down and sometimes create this error. I know why this error is producing. But I don't find any good solution which resolve this issue. I don't want to slow down my application.
Here is the code snip of my DB Context class.

```
    public DefaultContext() : base("name=DefaultContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DefaultContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

DB.cs

```
    private readonly DefaultContext _context = new DefaultContext(ConnectionConfiguration.GetConnectionString("DefaultContext"));
    private Repository<T> _repository;
    public Repository<T> Repository
    {
        get { return _repository ?? (_repository = new Repository<T>(_context)); }
    }
```

Reposirtory.cs

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    internal DefaultContext Context;
    internal DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public Repository(DefaultContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        DbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }
 }
```

Somewhere I've read about to use dependency injection (Ninject). Help will be appreciated. Thanks